# Protecting TIMEVALUE usage inside SUMPRODUCT from input errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First question here, thanks in advance for your patience and assistance!

I have a spreadsheet that contains course types (column A, e.g. "Lec" or "Dis"), enrollment numbers (column B, as integers), and session times (column C, string time interval e.g. "10:00AM - 01:00PM").

I need to sum the enrollment numbers for all classes of a certain type (say "Lec") that end before a certain time (say 3:00 PM). The following code accomplishes that:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A2:A8="Lec")), --(TIMEVALUE(MID(B2:B8,11,5)&" "&MID(B2:B8,16,2))<=TIMEVALUE("03:00 PM")), C2:C8)
```

The problem is that some of the session times may be blank, which renders a "#VALUE!" error. As best I can tell this is because TIMEVALUE is unable to accept an empty cell as input, so whenever that occurs it breaks the whole thing. I therefore need in this case for the formula to ignore the row and not progress to the various other evaluations.

I have attempted to protect the TIMEVALUE content behind various conditional statements, e.g. only considering that row if the time session length is correct (length=17). I have not been able to do this successfully, however. Nor have my internet searches found a similar-enough situation to use for help.

Because of the circumstances around this project, I am strongly interested in formula solutions before considering things like changing the overall spreadsheet format or adding dummy columns for computations. That said, I welcome any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, using [`AGGREGATE`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) as `SUM` does *not* skip errors if there is a Calculation in the formula.  Similarly, `IFERROR` and `ISERROR` only work properly with Ranges/Arrays when in an Array Formula, not when in `SUMPRODUCT`.  That's the easiest options out unless you want a calculation column.

However, all is not lost!  First, we reduce your `SUMPRODUCT` to a single argument with `*` in place of `,`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A8="Lec")*--(TIMEVALUE(MID(B2:B8,11,5)&" "&MID(B2:B8,16,2))<=TIMEVALUE("03:00 PM"))*C2:C8)
```

Next, we change this from `=SUMPRODUCT(`*`X`*`)` to `=SUM(IFERROR(`*`X`*`,0))`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--(A2:A8="Lec")*--(TIMEVALUE(MID(B2:B8,11,5)&" "&MID(B2:B8,16,2))<=TIMEVALUE("03:00 PM"))*C2:C8),0)
```

Just remember to press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] instead of just [Enter] to convert to an [Array Formula](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) - the formula will display in `{Curly brackets}`